# Better approach to Cyclic Rotation of Array

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, rotation

Using swift, I'm solving the following problem...

"A zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. Rotation of the array means that each element is shifted right by one index, and the last element of the array is moved to the first place. For example, the rotation of array A = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6] is [6, 3, 8, 9, 7] (elements are shifted right by one index and 6 is moved to the first place). The goal is to rotate array A K times; that is, each element of A will be shifted to the right K times."

---

I am using two slightly different approaches to solve above problem and a bit confused which one is better performance wise and complexity wise( No need to consider no. of lines of code)..

**# Solution1:**

```
import UIKit

public func solution(_ A : inout [Int], _ K : Int) -> [Int] {

    if (K < 0 || K > 100 || A.count == 0) {
        return [];
    }

    if (A.count == 1) {
        return A;
    }

    for _ in 0...(K - 1) {
        let lastIndex = A.removeLast()
        A.insert(lastIndex, at: 0)
    }


    return A
}
var tem = [1,2,3,4,5]
solution(&tem, 2)
print(tem)
```

**# Solution2:**

```
public func solution2(_ A : inout [Int], _ K : Int) -> [Int] {
    var ret: [Int] = [];

    if (K < 0 || K > 100 || A.count == 0) {
        return ret;
    }

    if (A.count == 1) {
        return A;
    }

    ret = A
    for i in 0...(K - 1) {
        ret[(i + K) % A.count] = A[i];
    }

    return ret
}
var tem2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
solution2(&tem2, 2)
print(tem)
```

Please help me decide which of two above solutions is better performance wise and why.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it and measure.

Comment: And have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264959/shift-elements-in-array-by-index for some good solutions.

Comment: I would just use array slicing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39153003/3141234

Comment: The `.insert(lastIndex, at: 0)` approach is definitely worse, each removal at the start is `O(N)`, and only done 1 spot at a time, rather than the full amount necessary

Comment: The usual trick for doing this quickly in place is to reverse the array, and then reverse the front and back portions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860895/c-c-eficient-method-of-rotating-an-array-without-using-build-in-functions-h/33860956#33860956